# Error: bad operand type for unary -: 'range' in Sigmoid function code

Tags: python-3.x

I am practicing codes for Sigmoid and Softmax with input range, x = range(-10,20) as,

```
def softmax(x):
    softmax_score = np.exp(x) / float(sum(np.exp(x)))
    return  softmax_score
```

---

This code is working! but,

```
def sigmoid(x):
    sigmoid_scores = [1 / float(1 + np.exp(- x))]
    return sigmoid_scores
```

---

gave me error,
*** TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'range'

I'd like to konw what makes the differnce between above two codes for the same input.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a `range`, and as the error says, you can't apply the `-` operator to it. You could, however, use a comprehension expression to apply `-` to every element in it:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    sigmoid_scores = [1 / float(1 + np.exp([-i for i in x]))]
    return sigmoid_scores
```

Comment: Thanks, but why def softmax(x): is working for same x without indicating the range?

Comment: @Clee I don't understand this statement. `x` is indeed a range - in `softmax` you don't manipulate it, so you can pass it to `exp` as-is